# JPA Query named parameter issue in Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, named-parameters

I have this method in my repository:

```java
@Query("""
SELECT items FROM ItemEntity items WHERE items.type = :type
AND (:idList IS NULL OR items.id IN :idList)
""")
List<Items> findItems(@Param("type") String type, @Param("idList") List<String> idList);
```

It works when `idList` is `null` or has only 1 item, but it gives me an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when `idList` contains more than 1 item:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
at java.base/java.util.Collections$EmptyList.get(Collections.java:4586) ~[na:na]
```

I don't know what's causing it.

Comment: According to me, this error has nothing to do with JPA. I think that the List<String> idList which are passed over the Parameter are realy Empty! Can you check bevor you call the method findItems method with System.out.println(""+idList.length()); what the size of the list is?

Comment: The list has contents, but when the list has more than 1 item then I'm getting that error.

Comment: did you try with System.out.println(""+idList.length()); bevor you call the findItems method? please try this. because the Exeptions meens that the List idList are empty.

Comment: yes I did before I posted the question, System.out.println(""+idList.size()) since it is List from the collections framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parentheses like this:

```
@Query("""
SELECT items FROM ItemEntity items WHERE items.type = :type
AND (:idList IS NULL OR items.id IN (:idList))
""")
```

Comment: Tried this one and it's the same 

Comment: Please check my answer in similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593358/jpa-query-annotation-problem-to-use-in-clause-with-java-arraylist Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Mar-Z, the coalesce(:idList) worked. thanks

Comment: Cool. Thanks for feedback. I have seen the coalesce(:idList) solution and tried it but it doesn't work for me. At least not with H2 database.