# Jpa @Query Annotation problem with using IN clause with java ArrayList

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem to with using an IN clause in jpa Query. When O use `c.id IN (1,7)` it works fine but when I use `c.id IN :categories` it gives me this error:

> org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CoercionException: Cannot coerce value [1, 7] [java.util.Arrays$ArrayList] as Long

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.events.dto.Event.ParticipantGetAllEventsDto(e, COUNT(p)) "
    + "FROM Event e JOIN FETCH e.reservation r JOIN FETCH r.salon s "
    + "LEFT JOIN r.participants p "
    + "JOIN e.categories c "
    + "WHERE (:title is null OR e.title LIKE %:title%) AND "
    + "(:isFree is null OR ((:isFree = true AND e.cost = 0) OR (:isFree = false AND e.cost >0 ))) AND "
    + "(:categories is null OR c.id IN (:categories) ) "
    + "GROUP BY e")
List<ParticipantGetAllEventsDto> getAll(@Param("title") String   title,@Param("categories") List<Long> categories ,@Param("isFree") boolean isFree);
```

I also checked `categories`'s value: it's an `arrayList` and its value is `[1,7]`

Comment: Try `coalesce(:categories) is null` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reproduced your settings and get the same error. It looks like JPQL can't handle the check `:myParameter IS NULL` if `myParameter` is a collection. If you remove the check for null the query works without issue.

Of course it is not what you wanted - to switch the IN clause on/off depending on a parameter.

**Workaround 1**

Introduce a separate boolean parameter like here:

```
    @Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE (:noList = true OR c.id IN (:theList))")
    List<Customer> findFromList(List<Long> theList, boolean noList);
```

**Workaround 2**

Use Criteria query instead.