# JPQL How to check if list contains any items from the input list

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpql

I need to check if a list contains any items from the input list.

```
@Query("""
SELECT items FROM ItemEntity items WHERE items.type = :type
AND (coalesce(:idList) IS NULL OR items.id IN (:idList)) <- this is ok
AND (coalesce(:sourceList) IS NULL OR :sourceList MEMBER OF items.sources) <-- this is not
""")
List<Items> findItems(@Param("type") String type, @Param("idList") List<String> idList,
List<String> sourceList);
```

sourceList is a list of strings that contains ['Canada', 'Sydney',...]

Similar to my previous [JPA Query named parameter issue in Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76588092/jpa-query-named-parameter-issue-in-repository) , it works when there is only one item in the list, and I get the same error when there is more than 1 item:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
at java.base/java.util.Collections$EmptyList.get(Collections.java:4586) ~[na:na]
```

so basically I need to check if the list from the db contains any (NOT all) items from the input list.

example:

Item:

- Gear

Source:

- Sydney
- Germany

and my input for sourceList is  ['Canada', 'Sydney']

then it should return the item Gear.

**EDIT**

as per Andrey Panfilov

```
SELECT items FROM ItemEntity items WHERE items.type = :type
AND (coalesce(:idList) IS NULL OR items.id IN (:idList)) <- this is ok
AND (coalesce(:sourceList) IS NULL OR exists (select 1 from items.sources s where s in (:sourceList)))
```

Comment: `exists (select 1 from items.sources s where s in (:sourceList))`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov, it worked! thanks, can you put your comment as an answer so I can mark it.